# How to query with 'after' timestamp criteria

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I want to filter data that only `start` timestamp happen before `finish` timestamp

Here's my data

```
id  finish               start
1   2018-02-06 13:24:23  2018-02-06 11:11:23
2   2018-02-06 17:25:01  2018-02-06 08:45:20
3   2018-02-06 05:45:19  2018-02-06 06:18:16
4   2018-02-08 12:23:51  2018-02-06 11:11:59
```

Here's what I want

```
id  finish               start
1   2018-02-06 13:24:23  2018-02-06 11:11:23
2   2018-02-06 17:25:01  2018-02-06 08:45:20
4   2018-02-08 12:23:51  2018-02-06 11:11:59
```

because `df['finish']` is before `df['start']` so id `3` is removed

Comment: My first idea is `df[df['finish'] > df['start']]`, but can you explain more why 3. row is removed?

Comment: that `df[df['finish'] > df['start']]` is works,

Comment: why `3` explanation is given

Comment: `2018-02-07 05:45:19  2018-02-06 06:18:16` - it is not before, not typo?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it should be `2018-02-06 05:45:19 2018-02-06 06:18:16`